# Split dependencies from _deploy.jar in Bazel's java_binary

Tags: java, docker, bazel

I'm building a Java project with bazel, using rules like this:

```
java_library(
  name="mylib"
  srcs = ...
  deps = ...
)

java_binary(
  name="mybin",
  main_class = ...
  runtime_deps = ["//:mylib"]
)
```

I can build this just fine with `bazel build //:mybin_deploy.jar`, with the result of that command being put into a docker image for execution elsewhere.  The jar file that gets created is currently about 200mb, but only about 1.5mb of that is my code, with the rest being dependencies.  Since all of the code is in a single JAR file it gets copied into the docker image as a single layer, so if I make a simple bug fix in my code I end up having to push the entire 200mb jar file up to our docker registry, which gets a bit old.

My current solution to this problem is to build both `//:mylib` and `//:mybin_deploy.jar`, and have a build phase in my docker image which deletes my code from the deploy jar; I then copy both jars into the final image.

```
FROM javieraviles/zip AS build
COPY mybin_deploy.jar /app/mybin_deps.jar
RUN zip -d /app/mybin_deps.jar "com/company/*"

FROM openjdk:18-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["java", "-cp", "/app/mybin_deps.jar:/app/libmylib-lib.jar", "com.Main"]
COPY --from=build /app/mybin_deps.jar /app/mybin_deps.jar
COPY libmylib-lib.jar /app/libmylib-lib.jar
```

So the question is: is there a better way to do this on the bazel side?  The only thing I can think of is writing something that can do the traversal of the dependencies myself so I don't have to try splitting things out of the `_deploy.jar`, but that seems like a lot of effort for something that the `java_library` rule can already do.  I don't think it matters much to me whether the dependencies are packaged into a single jar or separated out into their original jar files, as long as all the transitive dependencies are available.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `java_image` rule from rules_docker library:

https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/blob/master/java/image.bzl#L260

It creates a binary using `java_binary` but without bundling the dependencies inside and then creates a separate image layer with dependencies (note the use of `deps` instead of `runtime_deps`).

Comment: Looks interesting, I'll see what I can do with that.  Thanks!